# How to replace the string enclose in double quote using regex?

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I have used regex to find and replace the string enclose within double quotes. Below is the regex I have used. Output I got is new is placed before the regex.

```
int portNum = 5969;
var input = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\aaa\look.ts");
var outputFileText = Regex.Replace(input, @"baseurl(\s*)= (\s*).*?", @"baseurl = " + "\"http://localhost:" + portNum + "\"");
```

Output I got is

```
var baseurl = "http://localhost:5969/""http://www.google.com/";
```

Expected output is

```
var baseurl= "http://localhost:5969/"
```

Comment: typescript file content which contains the var baseurl....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use greedy quantifier `.*?` in the end otherwise it will match as little as possible. In this case, since there is nothing after `.*?` therefore it will match 0 characters.

To make it work, make it greedy to match till end:

```
int portNum = 5969;
var input = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\aaa\look.ts");
var outputFileText = Regex.Replace(input, @"baseurl(\s*)= (\s*).*",
                     @"baseurl = " + "\"http://localhost:" + portNum + "\"");
```